# Can't access mysql on amazon ec2

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I have 2 amazon ec2 instances.I want to connect from one to another. One has a Mysql database (instance 1). When I run the php code below on instance 2. I get a

> ec2-x-x-x-x.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com is currently unable to handle this request.

But when I run the same code on http://phpfiddle.org/ the code works. Why does it not work on my server?

```
<?php

// On WEB_SERVER    
$host="public Ip of instance 1";              // Host name
$username="test";    // Mysql usernam
$password="pass";           // Mysql password
$db_name="mydab";             // Database name
$db_port="3306";   

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name,$db_port);
 Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}else
{
    echo "connected";
}    
?>
```

Comment: Have you opened the MySQL port in the security group for the EC2 instance? In other words, are you allowing your server access?

Comment: @JayBlanchard- Yes, I am able to connect to the Db when I run the same code on http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: phpfiddle *is not your server*. Have you checked your security groups on your EC2 instance?

Comment: Additionally, you should use the *name* of your EC2 instance as the `$host`

Comment: @JayBlanchard- on which server do I have to open the MuSQL port. The server that has the mysql or the server im trying to access from?

Comment: @amanda45 pretty sure nothing to do with security groups because you said that it is connecting in phpfiddle. It would be more helpfull if you can post relavent logs file. And finally just to avoid confusion the mysql port should be open on the instance running mysql and not the one connecting to the same :)

Comment: Is this a VPC or classic? Also, have you considered using RDS instead of a second EC2 instance?

Comment: @Machavity-its a classic

Comment: @georoot-how can i get log files?

Comment: VPC is a good thing for cases like this, even for RDS.

Comment: This is a bad design.  First , it is not recommended to use EC2-Classic. Second, `ec2-x-x-x-x...` is a amazon assigned public domain name, you SHOULD not use this kind of connection method.  If you place both EC2 inside same VPC subnet, the connection between server should not be an issue.  The left over part should be configuring the EIP for Web.